# Running xUnit tests with vstest

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, xunit, dnx, vstest

I am trying to run my xUnit unit tests using `vstest.console.exe`, but no tests are found.

I am using `vstest.console.exe` from Visual Studio 2015, found in this location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\ Microsoft\TestWindow

Command run:

```
vstest.console.exe "C:\MyProject\artifacts\bin\UnitTest\Release\dnx451\UnitTest.dll" /TestAdapterPath:"C:\MyProject\packages"
```

Response:

> Starting test execution, please wait...
>
> Warning: No test is available
>   in the provided sources. Make sure that installed test discoverers &
>   executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and
>   try again.

I have also tried with the following TestAdapterPath arguments, but with the same problem:

```
/TestAdapterPath:"C:\MyProject\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio"

/TestAdapterPath:"C:\MyProject\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.1.0-beta4-build1109"

/TestAdapterPath:"C:\MyProject\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.1.0-beta4-build1109\build" 

/TestAdapterPath:"C:\MyProject\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio\2.1.0-beta4-build1109\build\_common"
```

The `project.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0-beta4-build3109",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta4-build134",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0-beta4-build1109"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  }
}
```

How am I to run these tests?

EDIT: Using the DNX beta6 runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Run `dnx . test` on your project

Comment: Is this not possible with vstest? The reason I ask is because VSO vNext Visual Studio Test step uses vstest.

Comment: @davenewza Is there any specific reason you want to run your test through vstest? any reservations running it through vstest?

Comment: Because this is what the VSO visual Studio test step uses with the new built platform.

Comment: Can you invoke `dnx . test` as part of the build script?

Answer (score 3):

You have to point `vstest` to project.json, and enable `UseVsixExtensions` flag.

So the actual unit tests run command should like like this:
`.\vstest.console.exe "..\test\YourProject.Tests\project.json" /UseVsixExtensions:true /logger:trx`

My VSO set up looks like this:
[image]

Reference: [Unit Tests with .NET Core and VSTS](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/08/unit-test-with-net-core-and-vsts/)